# How to detect if the state value has changed before a specific time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to detect if the page number *(which is created by useState hook)* has changed in last 5 seconds to make a conditional if statement. Is this possible in React/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to update the state you have that probably looks something like this:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
```

To something like this:

```
const [pageState, setPageState] = useState({ page: 0, lastUpdated: 0 })
```

This way, every time you update `page`, you also update `lastUpdated`, so you can do something like:

```
const updatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds = Date.now() - pageState.lastUpdated <= 5000
```

You can also store the `lastUpdated` value in a new state piece if you can't or don't want to change the one you already have.

Also, you can potentially use `setInterval` to continuously update `updatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds` (if you want to implement something like a progress bar) or just use `setTimeout` if you just need to know when the 5 seconds have passed, like in the example below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef(0)
  
  React.useEffect(() => () => {
    // Clear the tiemout when the component unmounts:
    clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
  }, [])
  
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [updatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds, setUpdatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds] = React.useState(false);
        
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1)
    setUpdatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds(true)
    
    setTimeout(() => {    
      setUpdatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds(false)
    }, 5000)
  });

  return (
    <button onClick={ handleClick } disabled={ updatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds }>
      { updatedWithinTheLastFiveSeconds ? 'Wait...' : `Go to page ${ page + 1 }` }
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

button {
  margin: 32px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I simply found a solution before reading your answer, using setTimeout method and changing state from true to false between 5s. Anyway I am accepting your answer my friend, since it is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "useEffect" with "useState". Create one useState variable for storing the lastupdation time stamp so that you can compare it with the latest time and check whether the difference is more than 5 second or not

```
  const [pageNum,setPageNum] = useState(1)
  const [lastChangedTime, setLastChangedTime] = useState(Date.now());

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update lastChangedTime when pageNum changes
    setLastChangedTime(Date.now());
  }, [pageNum]);
 
var isPageChanged = Date.now() - lastChangedTime >5000
```

Then you can use isPageChanged variable for any condition

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer, but a different method of settimeout method came into my mind and used it. I accepted another answer since he was the first

Comment: @JeremyFc   No worries, you can post your own method as solution so that another reader may find it worthy to use.